# why does visnu change lineage?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

does visnu change his lineage?  assuming rama and krsna are both avatars of visnu, and rama belongs to the solar (ikshvaku) and krsna to the lunar. why is there a change of lineage? does the change of lineage suggest anything about the lineage itself - the nature (svabhava) of the lineage? provide a reference if possible.

Comment: Because lineage does not matter. He incarnated as a fish, boar, in bhrigu clan etc. Lineages are irrelevant for the lord's Avatara.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter.

> *यदा यदा हि धर्मस्य ग्लानिर्भवति भारत ।
> अभ्युत्थानमधर्मस्य तदात्मानं सृजाम्यहम् ॥ b.g. 4.7 ॥*
>
> *Whenever and wherever there is a decline in religious practice, O descendant of Bharata, and a predominant rise of irreligion – at that time I descend Myself.*
>
> *परित्राणाय साधुनां विनाशाय च दुष्कृताम् ।
> धर्मसंस्थानार्थाय सम्भवामि युगे युगे ॥ b.g. 4.8 ॥*
>
> *To deliver the pious and to annihilate the miscreants, as well as to reestablish the principles of religion, I Myself appear, millennium after millennium.*

So, Lord Vishnu can take avatara in any form, any lineage. Like Lord Buddha avatar started a new religion only.

> *“tataḥ kalau sampravṛtte sammohāya sura-dviṣām | buddho nāmnāñjana-sutaḥ kīkaṭeṣu bhaviṣyati ||” (SB 1:3:24).*
>
> *“Then, in the beginning of Kali-yuga, the Lord (Vishnu) will appear as Lord Buddha, the son of Añjanā, in the province of Gayā, just for the purpose of deluding those who are envious of the faithful theist”.*

I hope this clarifies your queries.

Comment: thank u kind sir..buddha was also solar as i've read. does the change of lineage suggest anything about the lineage itself?  the nature of the lineage or such?

Comment: of course it does seem to mean that all of buddha's suffering prior to his enlightenment was a hoax...that is hard to believe, but i suppose it's possible

Comment: U can take patshuram's example he was a Brahman of bhrigu clan. Arjuna, the nara avatara was from kuru which is a lunar dynasty. So, it doesn't matter. As for Lord Buddha, yes he was born as surya vanshi n he left the kingdom n plus no1 says his life as a hoax. Anyways, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Common god doesn't see lineage he just take avatar or birth wherever he see there is a harm to dharma to teach the real dharma don't you know about dashavatar in which lord take birth as turtle half lion and as a fish just to make necessary changes in evolution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).